# Git shows "Everything up to date", but I can see gem files updated in my local, not updated in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I am building a rails application and I'm very new to Git. I am trying to update files in git, and although my local gemfile has been updated, when I try `git status`, `git add` . or `git commit` everything shows up as "Everything up to date" and "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

I am using Vagrant on windows

Comment: did you use `git add -A` (for all files), or `git add [your gemfile]`?

Comment: I tried both, but when i commit, i am getting "On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: @MaheshN On which branch you are working?other branch or `master` branch ?

Comment: If you look in your .gitignore file in the top level of the library, is there a file pattern that matches your file?

Comment: @benjic, I did not ignore any file that I am trying to upload to git.I am just trying to upload an updated gem file and other updated config files,

Comment: @MaheshN Can you share a link to the repo and the name of the file you updated? It sounds like you are attempting to stage a file that has been changed in the working directory, but no changes are added to the stage. This is often because the file has been once committed but either now matched in the `.gitignore` or the [`git update --assume-unchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) bit has been flipped.

Comment: What's output of following commands git branch -v and git remote -v?

Comment: Just make sure you are not inside detach head mode. if you are try this fix [detach head mode fix](http://learnwebtutorials.com/you-are-in-detached-head-state-how-fix)

Comment: You say you are using Vagrant on Windows.  Are the files in question on the Vagrant VM?  Is that a Linux VM?  And when you're running the commands, are you in Windows or in the VM?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git pull origin master` and then `git push origin master`

Note: check if you are on your on your main branch "origin master" by typing `git branch -a` and then try the above logic

you should see below message on trying `git branch -a`

`* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master`

Comment: Yes, I did try git branch-a and I got the below                                     * master
 remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
 remotes/origin/master

Comment: This is the message                                                                                     * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

Comment: Okay, could you try push, if it doesn't work try `git diff <filename>` and see if there is any difference

Comment: git diff doesn't return anything

Comment: Sorry for wrong info its `git diff -- filename.txt` replace filename and extension with ur gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem. I have been commit'ing from a different folder, where as my actual app existed within the root and was not at the root.